# Is it possible to share a network through LAN?

Tags: networking, connection-sharing

I wish to do the following setup:

- PC1: Windows 7 with 2 Ethernet ports, connected to Internet
- PC2: Mac OS X 10.7 with 1 Ethernet port

I want to share the internet connection to PC2 through LAN since PC1 has 2 Ethernet ports.
How do I do it?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). Your question fails to meet some of the quality standards for ServerFault and consequently I'm voting to close it.

Comment: you might have more luck on poweruser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can setup Internet Connection Sharing:

Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> click on the Internet Connection to open the status Dialog -> button Properties -> tab page Sharing -> check the Option to allow other users in the Network to share the Internet Connection

You might also take a look at the [Microsoft pages](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-a-shared-internet-connection-using-ics-internet-connection-sharing).